# Opening separate windows with Start

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am tring to open several instance of IE with the start command in a batch file. For example I want to open www.google.com and www.yahoo.com at the same time in separate windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Aaron

Answer (score 2):

```
$>start iexplore http://google.com
$>start iexplore http://yahoo.com
```